# How to split characters with quotation marks as its condition?

Tags: r

I want to split by `,`

**INPUT:**

`"Hello, my name is',' Mark',' I am a happy guy."`

**OUTPUT:**

`Hello, my name is Mark I am a happy guy.`

This is what I've tried:

```
splitted<-str_split_fixed(text, "\',\'",Inf)
```

Comment: Try `gsub("\\',\\'", "", text)`

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you use `str_split_fixed` instead of `str_split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is not clear. On the one hand it seeks to "split" a string but on the other the expected output suggest a mere transformation of the string. If the latter is the case, then this works:

```
gsub("','", "", text)
[1] "Hello, my name is Mark I am a happy guy."
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Ruehlemann points out, the question is not quite clear. If it was meant to split the string by `','` (including the single quotes as split), this appears to work:

```
library(stringr)
text<- "Hello, my name is',' Mark',' I am a happy guy."

str_split_fixed(text, "\',\'", Inf)

 [,1]                [,2]    [,3]                
[1,] "Hello, my name is" " Mark" " I am a happy guy."
```

But I don't think you need `str_split_fixed`. The function `str_split` suffices.

```
str_split(text, "','")

[[1]]
[1] "Hello, my name is"  " Mark"              " I am a happy guy."
```

Comment: That's not the result the OP wants

Comment: Well, the answer fits better to the question before you edited it. It was asked to split by `','` not by `,`.

Comment: That was a co-edit; the part you mention was edited by someone else!

Comment: No prob. The important point in the OP seems to be the expected output: `Hello, my name is Mark I am a happy guy`